# In Apache Camel, for which component will create endpoints if it's not exist?

Tags: apache-camel

I'm new to Camel, and have some basic questions which can't found the answers online. Please help and I'm appreciate it.

1. I have read many example online, and saw bunch example like this:

   from(direct:A).to(jms:queue:B)

   But didn't see any configuration for them. My question is what will happen if the direct doesn't exist? How about from(jms:queue:A).to(direct:A)? and what about the other components?
2. For this example, what's the execution order? does it pass the original message to B first, then process and pass to C?

   from(direct:A)
   .to(jms:B)
   .process(something)
   .to(jms:C)

Answer (score 0):

Direct is an in memory queue, provided by Camel. Prior it Camel 3, it was bundled with the `camel-core` module and you would not need any configuration at all in order to use the direct component. However, due to sake of modularity, since Camel 3, direct has been made its own component and in order to use it `camel-direct` needs to be imported.

Jms on the other hand is a generic component, using which you can implement connectivity to different Jms providers such as ActiveMq(though in Camel activemq has it's own component), IBM MQ, Weblogic JMS server, and others.

For your 1st question, if `direct` doesn't not exist, you need to import the direct component into your build. If the uri provided to the component is not present, Camel will create its own. This is true for most of the Camel components. One of the most common is the `file` component, which is used to pick up files from a given directory. If the given directory is not present, Camel is smart enough to create the directory. Obviously, these are default behaviours and you have a lot of control to pick and choose how you want your route to behave.

For your second question, the route will be processed entirely in order, which is, the message will be picked up from the `direct:A`, then will be sent to `jms:B`. After that it will be processed using the `something` processor and will finally be sent to `jms:c`.

The thing to note here is that the `direct:A` is just an example to show the syntax of a route. You can use any component which can act as a consumer.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is what i need!

Comment: hi, i have a extra question here: i saw something like from(direct:A) .to(processor) .process(processor) in project code, what's the different between to and process to call the processor?

Comment: Firstly, I don't think there is a `to(processor)` in Camel. Your project might have a custom implementation of a bean. The processor is a special class which implements the Processor interface.

Comment: yes it is a processor class which implements the processor interface, which im so confuse in this case what's the different between them.